# Grafana: how to divide 2 set of data (one series, one constant list)

Tags: prometheus, grafana

say I have 5 machines with different memory sizes, and I can get memory usage in bytes from one process. How to show memory usage in percentage? (we do not have permission to modify the target process to query and dump host total memory bytes)

I know about how to divide 2 series as:

1. create a query
2. use `seriesA{} / seriesB{}`

Now we can get a series query to get memory usage bytes like `time=0 | a=200, b=300, c=200, d=400, e=100; time=1 | ...; ...`; and we can define a constant variable with multiple values like `1000, 1000, 2000, 5000, 2000`; how to divide the 2 set of data and show memory usage in percentage?

Here is an example that does not work:

1. create a query (A) `seriesA{}`
2. create a query (B) `constantValues`
3. create expression `$A / $B` (unexpected result)

datasource is `prometheus`

thx!

Comment: Important details is missing - what is your datasource type?

Comment: @JanGaraj thx for pointing it out, it is `prometheus`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems no good answer; and I figured out the traditional way: create 5 queries by using 5 machine label filter and each divided by different memory total bytes.

- QueryA: memory{label=a} / valueA
- QueryB: memory{label=b} / valueB
- QueryC: memory{label=c} / valueC
- QueryD: memory{label=d} / valueD
- QueryE: memory{label=e} / valueE